# How can I get information (like println()) when running a simulation on an actual iPhone - I need this for better debugging

Tags: iphone, debugging

How can I get information (like println()) when running a simulation on an actual iPhone - I need this for better debugging
I have a problem of saving a file on my albums, the program does not crash but the video recording is not saved and I need to locate the problem. Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try save log information with a local DB and retrieve them later

Comment: I solved it by adding a label that receives updates during execution

Comment: if you just display the info you could miss some information if you dont save them and appear too fast

Comment: At the end, I added a label that prints  on the screen